# Where can i find the changelog of a snap package

Tags: snap

I am just curious: Where can i find the changelog of a snap package?

I want to know what has changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the snap in question. Snaps are different from Debian packages in the archive in that they're not necessarily open-source. They're just blobs of bits. As a result, there is no requirement to *have* a changelog. Even if it *does* have one, it may not be within the snap itself. Let's take a look at Nextcloud as an example for where you might find one. First of all, look at the info for the snap:

```
$ snap info nextcloud
name:      nextcloud
summary:   Nextcloud Server - A safe home for all your data
publisher: Nextcloud✓
contact:   https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap
[...]
```

Visit that "contact" url and you'll find its [changelog right in the root](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/blob/master/CHANGELOG). [Each tag/release](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/releases/tag/15.0.7snap1) also includes the changelog snippet.

However, I reiterate: this is specific to the Nextcloud snap (which I maintain). Every snap may do it differently, and the source code (and changelog) may not be available to you.

Comment: What a pity :( but thx for the explanation!