# Where is the changelog for Firefox snap package?

Tags: firefox, snap, changelog

Nothing in `snap info firefox`, nothing on https://snapcraft.io/firefox

[Where can i find the changelog of a snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138854/where-can-i-find-the-changelog-of-a-snap-package) and [Is there a security changelog for Canonical snap packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362946/is-there-a-security-changelog-for-canonical-snap-packages) didn't help either.

And I mean specifically difference between updates in the snap package, like `103.0.1` and `103.0.1-1`, not the Firefox changelog.

Comment: did you  read through [this snapcraft resource](https://snapcraft.io/install/changelog/ubuntu). Might installing `Changelog` resolve your issue?

Comment: `changelog` is a different snap package that is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: sorry for trying to be helpful 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical does not build the Firefox snap package. While Ubuntu members contribute to Firefox (including Canonical engineers), the snap is built by Mozilla directly from their own source code. The snap YAML is part of that Mozilla source code, hosted on Mozilla's infrastructure.

- [Example](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/log/tip/taskcluster/docker/firefox-snap/firefox.snapcraft.yaml.in) showing how snap YAML is hosted by Mozilla, not by Canonical.

Mozilla provides two changelogs:

- The source code changelog for developers: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/shortlog/ . It includes options for various branches (the 'default' branch might be what you are seeking)
- The release notes for users. Example for v103.0.1: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/103.0.1/releasenotes/

Mozilla does not release snap-specific release changelogs. Their snap releases are the vanilla upstream releases.